# Not able to run angular material docs on locally

Tags: angular-material

Environment: Windows 7, npm 2.11.3, bower 1.4.1, gulp CLI 3.9.0

I Cloned angular material (https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v0.10.1) using WebStorm. I followed the (https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v0.10.1/docs) to install angular-material locally.

At root directory `/`

I run `npm install` it runs (with some warnings) and downloaded its dependencies (my `npm -v` is 2.11.3)

In run `bower install` but its gives following

`D:\material>bower install
bower    ENOENT No bower.json present`

then I run `gulp docs` to build docs, it was build and created `/dist` folder at root directory. after I run the `gulp server` command to live reload. Its said `Webserver started at http://0.0.0.0:8080` I saw on bower but no luck, also tried alternativly as `http://localhost:8080` still there is no luck.

One more alternative using httpster, I installed it and run `httpster -p 8080 -d ./dist/docs` it said `Starting HTTPster v1.0.1 on port "8080" from ./dist/docs`
 again i browse `localhost:8080` then its gives me error in index page on developer tool of crome as below

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=material.components.menu
angular.js:4369 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=docsApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

Please help what can I do to get my luck.

Answer (score 0):

Paul (ngmaterial group on google) solved my problem, However site is loading demo pages not working.

> Try renaming _menu.js in material-0.10.1\src\components\menu to menu-a.js. In my case that ensured the two js files were added in the correct order.