# Unbale to run angular-material docs locally

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, angular-material

I'm trying to run Angular-Material docs locally. I followed the instructions mentioned in the link
[material/docs at master](https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/docs)

> Successfully executed `npm install` without errors (but with npm version warning - I'm just considering that thsi) after lots of googling and looking at SO answers.

When I execute `bower install` it throws the following error.

```
G:\Angular\material-master\docs\app>bower install
bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present
```

When I googled it I just got this link https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2407 saying

> we no longer use bower within the /angular/material repository. Now you use only need to use npm.

[image: Github Issues Screenshot]

And if I proceed to `gulp docs` I again get the error as below:

```
G:\Angular\material-master\docs\app>gulp docs
[19:37:47] Working directory changed to G:\Angular\material-master\docs
[19:37:48] Using gulpfile G:\Angular\material-master\docs\gulpfile.js
[19:37:48] Task 'docs' is not in your gulpfile
[19:37:48] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Where am I going wrong, how do I get it working? Any help is appreciated.
PS: I am not a pro at using node or at using angular. I also tried HTTPster method mentioned alternatively, but no luck.

```
G:\Angular\material-master\docs\app>httpster -p 8080 -d ./dist/docs
Starting HTTPster v1.0.1 on port "8080" from ./dist/docs
GET / 404 10ms
GET /index 404 2ms
GET /demo 404 2ms
GET /help 404 1ms
```

And also tried the same from root directory with a random hope, but just got same results.

My questions is not similar to
[Not able to run angular material docs on locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011805/not-able-to-run-angular-material-docs-on-locally) which states a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your installation is not complete. Please follow the steps.

Step 1: Get the Master Project by using git https://github.com/angular/material.git. OR Clone it locally. 
Step 2: Run npm install. 
Step 3: gulp build & gulp docs (install gulp first if you don't have).  
Step 4: gulp server. (This start project at localhost:8080).

**Sometimes it causing problem to run u can alternatively run it by going one step further.**

Install http-server by using following command.
***npm install http-server -g***

then run using
  **http-server dist/docs -p 8080 -a 127.0.0.1** 
Project available at http://localhost:8080/